# TCL wildcard/glob usage within file name

Tags: windows, tcl, modelsim, questasim

I have code that is like this:

```
...
proc myProc {first last} {
    for { set i $first } { $i <= $last } { incr i } {
        set i_cur "PlainText$i"
        <command> [glob ./../myDir/${i_cur}*]
    }
}
```

When I run this, any file that has nothing after the number will run fine. But if there is something after the number then it doesn't.
For example, I have the valid files named `PlainText0.txt`, `PlainText00.txt`, and `PlainText1_Plaintext.txt`. The first two work and `PlainText1_Plaintext.txt` doesn't.

Basically, I do not think I am using a glob/wildcard correctly, but don't know how.

Comment: Works for me.   Does <command> work properly when passed multiple filenames?

Comment: @BradLanam, if I remove all of the text after the number (i.e. change `text1_stuff.txt` to `text1.txt` then it works like a charm and iterates through all of my files. If I do not, then it does not process). If I rename a portion of them, it iterates correctly though the renamed ones and does not work from the un-renamed ones and on.

Answer (score 1):

The usual issues with this sort of thing are when you've got the glob for what you want wrong, or when you've got a command that needs the *list* returned by `glob` expanded.

If it's that the command needs the list expanded, you need to use:

```
<command> {*}[glob ...]
```

That `{*}` in front of the bracket expands the results into multiple arguments. Sometimes, this instead requires you to iterate over the results and pass them in one at a time:

```
foreach filename [glob ...] {
    <command> $filename
}
```

When it comes to the glob itself, you're not quite clear whether `PlainText1_stuff.txt` is acceptable to you or not. However, it is matched by the pattern `PlainText1*`. If it isn't acceptable, maybe you need `PlainText1.*`; the extra `.` is important to what is matched here.

Also, consider using the `-directory` option to `glob` as it makes your code clearer (*especially* if you're on one of the platforms that allows glob metacharacters in filenames).

---

Overall, you're perhaps looking at something like this:

```
<command> {*}[glob -directory ../myDir PlainText$i.*]
```

You can use a helper variable if you want.

Comment: Perhaps the `-nocomplain` option would be applicable as well.

Comment: @Donal Fellows, To clarify if `PlainText1_stuff.txt` is valid, I updated the question. It is:
I have all of the files I want in a directory, and can iterate and run my <command> (which is application specific. eg. QuestaSim is adding the file to a project and compiling an RTL source file), all of the files without more characters after the number work and all of the files with characters after do not. All of the files are valid and should work.

Comment: Then go with: foreach file [glob ..."PlainText*"] { do_something_with $file } . If you get more files then you wanted, either craft beter mask for glob, or use [string match] or [regexp] to check $file further.