# How to `rm -rf *` in TCL

Tags: tcl, delete-file, vivado

I want to delete all files in a directory using TCL. (I'm using Xilinx Vivado's TCL console under Win 10.) I found that in [TCL documentation](https://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.4/TclCmd/file.htm#M12) that

```
file delete ?-force? ?- -? pathname ?pathname ... ?
```

should work.
But

```
file delete -force -- [glob *]
```

does nothing.
What's the wrong with that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make that

```
  file delete -force -- {*}[glob *]
```

... so that the path names returned by `[glob]` are turned into multiple arguments to `[file delete]` (using the expansion operator `{*}`), rather than one argument representing the one list of a path names (read by `[file delete]` as one, well complex file path).

Alternatively, on Tcl older than 8.5, use an explicit loop:

```
 foreach path [glob *] {
    file delete -force -- $path
 }
```

Comment: Expansion of `[glob]` results for use in command calls, e.g., `[file]`, is a common theme here, see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40143368/tcl-wildcard-glob-usage-within-file-name.

Answer (score 3):

Additional things for you do consider:

1. do you need to be concerned about deleting files, not directories? Consider the `-type` option for [the `glob` command](https://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/glob.htm#M11).
2. if you need to work recursively, don't reinvent the wheel and use tcllib. The [`fileutil::traverse`](https://core.tcl.tk/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/www/tcllib/files/modules/fileutil/traverse.html) and [`fileutil`](https://core.tcl.tk/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/www/tcllib/files/modules/fileutil/fileutil.html) packages are relevant.