# TCL delete file

Tags: file, tcl, eval

I use the below command to delete file in TCL. But it errors out, when the file does not exist.

Am I correct to say the "nocomplain" will prevent it from erroring out?
If not, what options, can I use to stop it from error out when file does not exist?

```
eval file delete [glob nocomplain a.txt b.txt]
```

Comment: Why are you using `eval`? Use `{*}` to turn a list into individual arguments.

Comment: And see https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/glob.htm with regards to 'nocomplain'.

Comment: Or just `file delete a.txt b.txt` since you don't have any wildcards in those `glob` patterns.

Comment: This has been asked many times, search for "[tcl] file delete glob" and find e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54255592/how-to-rm-rf-in-tcl

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation for `file delete`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/file.htm#M12) says:

> Trying to delete a non-existent file is not considered an error.

So you can just use `file delete a.txt b.txt`. There's no need to use `glob` in your example because you don't have any wildcard patterns to match.

If you did, [the documentation for `glob`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/glob.htm) describes the `-nocomplain` option to avoid raising an error if no files match. Note the leading dash.

Finally, you can use [argument expansion](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/Tcl.htm#M9) instead of that ugly looking `eval`. Something like:

```
file delete {*}[glob -nocomplain a*.txt]
```